# PMD and Salesforce

Tags: pmd

Does anyone maybe know how to disable some rules from Apex PMD, for example, I want to disable this one "ClassNamingConventions".
I don't want to show me warning related to that rule in .csv file downloaded after running `sfdx scanner`?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to exclude it from a particular class/method** you can use the [@SupressWarnings](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html) annotation.
For your particular scenario it should be:

```
@SuppressWarnings('PMD.ClassNamingConventions')
public class Bar {
    void bar() {
        int foo;
    }
}
```

**If you want to exclude the rule for all your codebase** then you should:

1. Create a [PMD ruleset xml file](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html);
2. Add that rule as an exclusion on your `pmd-ruleset.xml` file. Something such as:

> ```
> <rule ref="category/apex/codestyle.xml" >
>     <exclude name="ClassNamingConventions"/>    
> </rule>
> ```

3. Run the sfdx:scanner command including the `--pmdconfig` flag to point out the location of PMD rule reference XML file.

Comment: And I suppose I need to create ```pmd-ruleset.xml``` file because I can not find it now. But where to put that file? And is there any other config I have to setup in order to PMD can read (use) that file?

Comment: Correct. Updated my original answer to include a hyperlink to the documentation regarding rulesets.
Regarding the other config you have to setup is to include the --pmdconfig flag on the sfdx:scanner command to include the ruleset file locaton. Here for more details: https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/en/scanner-commands/run/

Comment: I have one more problem, this is my rule set xml:  
`<ruleset name="myruleset"
  xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 https://pmd.sourceforge.io/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>My ruleset</description>

    <rule ref="category/apex/codestyle.xml" >
        <exclude name="ClassNamingConventions"/>    
    </rule>
</ruleset>`
but now it exclude not only "ClassNamingConventions" but, for example, "ApexDoc", "CyclomaticComplexity" and lot of others.

Comment: @mhdev you need to define all the categories and/or individual rules which you want to include in the file as well.
As an example: to include all the rules which belong to the BestPractices category you need to add to your ruleset <rule ref="category/apex/bestpractices.xml"/> 

You can see all the rules here: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex.html